# When was first security screen door instaled in Seoul metro

Tags: 20th-century, technology, transportation, korea

My task is to document Seouls metro history. However, I'm from Czech Republic which limits selection of sites I can get data from. (I don't speak Korean, and google translate usually fails).

Also, Seouls is relatively new so it's history is not as documented as coustruction of old European metros.

An information that I miss very much is date of the first sucessflly instaled platform security door and in which station was it.

Comment: I added the Korea, transportation and technology tags. Which tags are you missing?

Comment: I guess these were exacly the ones I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally, after all google searches failed, I had to search manually and now I must admint that the information is available even in english.

**A:** The first screen door system was installed on 4. November 2005 at Sadang Station.

Source: [Seoul metro official site](http://www.seoulmetro.co.kr/eng/page.jsp?code=A040020000)